# How to display filtered out files in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, java-8

I am using the following code to filter out files in Java Swing (using Java 8)

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
chooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(true);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

CustomFileFilter cffOne = new CustomFileFilter(null, "Directories Only", true);
CustomFileFilter cffTwo = new CustomFileFilter(".vi", "CAT Files (*.vi)", false);
CustomFileFilter cffThree = new CustomFileFilter(".hrd","HRRD Files (*.hrd)", false);
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(cffOne);
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(cffTwo);            
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(cffThree);
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
chooser.setDialogTitle("Select a directory or file(s)");
chooser.setApproveButtonText("OK");

SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(chooser);

PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener = new PropertyChange(chooser);

chooser.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);

int ret = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       // ..          
}
```

The filter works fine. Now my question is when the filter is selected, can we just disable the non matching files and display them as greyed out instead of hiding them?

Comment: Oh finally I met the guy who activates the metal look & feel voluntarily. But seriously, this has not been foreseen by the API. It might be possible, but will likely be very hackish.

Comment: @Holger Yeah, had to get a uniform look and feel across platforms. Hence the metal look and feel option. What will be the hackish way? Any suggestions?

Comment: `javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI` and `sun.swing.FilePane` seem to be a good start for research.